# Does Puma have something like Apache's "Location" tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

I'm using Puma (version 3.11.0) as the web server for a Rails application (Rails version 5.1.4).  I need the whole application to be SSL encrypted, but I need one particular route to also have the SSL "verify_mode" set to peer.  In Apache, I would normally use a "Location" or "LocationMatch" block to configure the SSL options differently from the rest of the site.

How can I do the same thing with Puma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally agree with @user3309314.

Exposing Puma to the internet directly (or exposing any application server, for that matter), isn't a great idea.

Web servers (unlike application servers) are designed to be in the front, protecting application servers from the cruel world...

...and along the way, they should be the ones to handle SSL/TLS (along with DoS attacks and other annoying concerns).

So use nginx or apache to forward requests to your Ruby application(s) and if you need a special TLS/SSL rule for a specific path, do that with nginx or apache.

Puma doesn't (and IMHO shouldn't) support the feature you're asking about.

**EDIT** (some of the information given in the comments + explanations)

It's best to think of application servers as a "bridge" between the host machine's routing layer (nginx/apache) and the applications.

It's the host routing layer (nginx/apache) that filters and routes certain host names and paths to certain applications (or the same application with different headers / variables / requirements).

The application server's job is to simply "bridge" between the host routing layer and the actual application, translating between the different data formats (HTTP data to Ruby objects and back).

In order to support the feature you're asking about, the application server should perform the same functions as the host routing layer (routing the correct host name / path to the correct application with the correct changes)

This would violate any "separation of concerns" as well as add redundancy to the system, inflicting a performance penalty (not to mention the larger code base that duplicates the same task in different modules).

This is the reason why, IMHO, these features should **not** get coded into Ruby application servers.

Comment: In production, Puma would not be used as the web server (we will likely be using Apache).  However, I would like to mimic this behaviour in Puma for development, as using Apache for development is a pain.

Comment: @Rossman , I’m sorry to say that it is what it is. You won’t get that functionality on Puma and it wouldn’t get coded in. The application server serves a whole application, it doesn’t perform any routing or proxying, so the feature you’re looking for isn’t feasible. It just isn’t an option, really.

Comment: @Rossman  P.S. I’m the author of the iodine Websocket/HTTP application server, so I know what I’m talking about when I say Puma won’t be able to offer this feature. It just goes against the Rack architecture upon which RoR was built.

Comment: @user3309314 I don't need SSL for development, per se.  But I'm trying to get the verify client certificate capability in development since it's going to be an authentication mechanism.  So the rest of SSL just comes with it.  I could make the whole Puma configuration verify the peer certificate, but it slows things down significantly, and that's not how the app is supposed to work anyway.

Comment: @Myst Not sure I agree with the idea that it "shouldn't" support this feature.  However, the question wasn't philosophical.  If the feature is not there, then it's just not there.  Best answer.

Comment: @Rossman, I updated my answer to explain my opinion about the issue. I apologize if I came off being high handed. It's true that it's just my opinion and I may be wrong, but I hope I convinced you.

Comment: @Myst, I assume by that same argument you disagree with concurrency in Puma.  Certainly that's not a concern of an application server.

Comment: @Rossman - actually, I find concurrency to be a very big concern for an application server. If the application server is a "bridge", than concurrency is what keeps things moving along (kinda' like traffic lanes in a real bridge). [Rack](https://rack.github.io) applications are often slower than nginx/apache by orders of magnitude (it's in the nature of their work) and concurrency is the way for an application server bridges this gap.

Comment: @Rossman However, I'm not sure Puma should provide SSL/TLS. I think this might be confusing for some developers. I do realize this feature has it's uses (internal infrastructure traffic isn't always safe), but I think it's a concession made to work around a larger design flaw in data security rather than an optimal design (IMHO, it would make more sense to encrypt the data than to secure the transport layer).

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that Puma supports this.

But you can configure Nginx or Apache as a reverse proxy, so requests get forwarded to the Puma application server, and you can configure SSL options as you need.

Comment: I will likely be using Passenger with Apache to replace Puma in production.  This question is more about how to mimic that configuration for development so I don't have to do some kludge to have my cake and eat it too.